# Repopulate Excel merged cells

Tags: excel, merge

I need to export a series of 5000 line excel documents to mySQL.  The problem is the excel files have been merged repeatedly.  (See link to screenshot: http://cgtest.forakergroup.com/images/excel.png )

```
     A1    CHARITY    NUM     AMT   
+    A2    name       1      $100
| +  A3               2      $105
| |  A4               2      $105
| L  A5               5      $105
L    A6               5      $105  
+    A7    name2      1      $100
| +  A8               2      $105
| |  A9               2      $105
| L  A10              5      $105
L    A11              5      $105
```

I need to insert the charity name (currently in A2) in each of the subsequent columns where it has been merged (A3, A4 etc.).

Is there a function within excel that will repopulate merged cells?

Comment: You can unmerge all cells and then write a macro to fill all blanks with the value of the first non-blank cell above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following macro will fill in all blanks as long as all the cells have been unmerged.

```
Sub Fill_Empty()
Dim oRng As Range
Set oRng = Selection
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Font.Bold = False
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
oRng.Copy
oRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Thanks to Levasseur for the suggestion to write a macro.

Answer (score 1):

If you are requiring what I think you are then a function is not necessary (nor code). Just select the relevant column, Home > Editing - Find & Select, Blanks, key `=`, <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Unless I'm doing it wrong then that only changes one group at a time.  The macro updates the entire sheet.